# Dockerized Riak cluster - dynamic container IP

Tags: docker, riak

I am trying to run Riak cluster in docker containers. Cluster is starting and working, but if I restart it, IPs of the nodes get changed, and nodes won't start until I remove contents of `/var/lib/riak/ring` directory.

Is it possible to force Riak somehow to identify joined nodes using different method than relying on IP addreses?

Comment: If you haven't seen it already I would check out the following extensive blog post about running Riak KV and TS in docker containers: http://basho.com/posts/technical/running-riak-in-docker/

Answer (score 1):

Erlang node names are formed like `<localpart>@<domainpart>` as long as all nodes in the cluster can resolve `<domainpart>` to an IP address the cluster will be able to communicate (assuming no network/firewall issues).

The most common methods would be to use DNS names with a network-local DNS server, or the /etc/hosts files to provide an IP for each name when it changes.